# Using combo-box as filter to show chart by time in vb.net using sql

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to show total sales charts by (Day,week, month, year) using items in combo box as filter querying from sql in vb.net. Please help. My codes are below, which throws the error saying 'cannot find table 0'.

```
 cboxGroupBy.Items.Insert(0, "Day")
    cboxGroupBy.Items.Insert(1, "Week")
    cboxGroupBy.Items.Insert(2, "Month")
    cboxGroupBy.Items.Insert(3, "Year")

    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT Date = DATEPART('" + Me.cboxGroupBy.Text + "', Date),                                                            
                 SUM (Amount) AS Amount 
                 FROM Sales                            
                 GROUP BY DATEPART('" + Me.cboxGroupBy.Text + "', Date)")

        Chart2.DataSource = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0)
        Chart2.Series.Clear()
        Chart2.Series.Add("Total Revenue")
        Chart2.Series("Total Revenue").XValueMember = "Date"
        Chart2.Series("Total Revenue").YValueMembers = "Amount"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quote from the `DatePart()` function. No need to pass Day or Week etc. in single quote. Here is your modified query.

```
 SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT Date = DATEPART(" + Me.cboxGroupBy.Text + ", Date),                                                            
                 SUM (Amount) AS Amount 
                 FROM Sales                            
                 GROUP BY DATEPART(" + Me.cboxGroupBy.Text + ", Date)")
```

Comment: I removed single quote but still not working. Thanks.

Comment: I get the same error "cannot find table 0". Thanks.

Comment: @ Krishnraj I got it. It works now. Thanks a lot. It was single quote as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get the current date, so use GETDATE() (if your DB is Sql Server) in your initial query.If it's something else, check out how to get the current date.

so:

```
  SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT Date = DATEPART('" + Me.cboxGroupBy.Text + "', GETDATE()),                                                            
                 SUM (Amount) AS Amount 
                 FROM Sales                            
                 GROUP BY DATEPART('" + Me.cboxGroupBy.Text + "', GETDATE())")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I changed as you suggested but it is still NOT working. Any further suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: I am using sql server. Thanks.